# Using link_to to only call a function in rails when the link is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to rails.  I'm trying to call a function check() only when a link is clicked, but the controller will also call the function every time the view loads.

**Routes:**
routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :articles
```

**Controller:**
articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    helper_method :check
    def new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    def check
        puts "check"
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
        end
```

**Model:** article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

**View:** index.html.erb

```
<h1>
  <%= link_to 'Call on click', :onclick => check() %> 
</h1>
```

Comment: I misspoke, you're *calling* check during the construction of the link string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call some route from a `link_to` try

`link_to "Call on click", controller: "articles", action: "check"`

and then just add a route `get 'articles/check'`

Answer (score 0):

inside your click function add the following statement to prevent the controller's action to be invoked

```
function click(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   your previous app logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb` add this:

```
get '/articles/check' => 'articles#check', as: :check_article
```

Then in your view you should do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Check article", check_article_path, remote: true %>
```

Notice the `remote:` option, it will tell rails to send the request via ajax instead of loading a new page (Im assuming this is the intended behavior).

Now, since you are sending the request via ajax, Rails should respond the request with some piece of javascript. Would be something like this in CoffeeScript:

```
#views/articles/check.js.coffee
$ ->
  $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert "Article was checked."
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused between `sever-side` (Rails) & `client-side` (JS) events.

---

Consider the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles do
  get :check, on: :collection #-> url.com/articles/check
end

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def check
    # do something
  end
end
```

The above will allow you to use...

```
<%= link_to "Check", articles_check_path %>
```

This will fire every time a link is "clicked", indeed it will cause your browser to take you to the new action / view you're trying to see.

The above is *server side* functionality. It's standard [`HTTP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

---

You're confusing the above with *javascript*:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var check = function() {
  // do something
}
```

The above is client-side *only*, and can only be called with the `onclick` / `.on("click"` event handler in javascript:

```
<%= link_to "Check", some_path, onclick: "return check();" %>
```

*This* is client-side, and only works with elements loaded into the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). It's typically used to give extra functionality to your application's front-end.